# Format the last column with separator :

Tags: unix, awk, scripting

I have an awk command

```
awk '{printf "%-11s %-24s %-16s %-1s %-6s %-1s %-1s %-7s %-1s %-1s\n", $1, $2, $3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}' fhost2
```

That output this

```
GBL-SVC-ES1 GBL-esx403.ad.gbl.com 10008C7CFF652604 1 Module 7 1 FC_Port 7 1
GBL-SVC-ES1 GBL-esx403.ad.gbl.com 10008C7CFF652604 1 Module 8 1 FC_Port 8 1
GBL-SVC-ES1 GBL-esx403.ad.gbl.com 10008C7CFF652604 1 Module 9 1 FC_Port 9 1
GBL-SVC-ES1 GBL-esx403.ad.gbl.com 10008C7CFF20D0A8 1 Module 7 1 FC_Port 7 3
```

How can i make this output look like this.

```
GBL-SVC-ES1 GBL-esx403.ad.gbl.com 10008C7CFF652604 1:Module:7 1:FC_Port:7:1
GBL-SVC-ES1 GBL-esx403.ad.gbl.com 10008C7CFF652604 1:Module:8 1:FC_Port:8:1
GBL-SVC-ES1 GBL-esx403.ad.gbl.com 10008C7CFF652604 1:Module:9 1:FC_Port:9:1
GBL-SVC-ES1 GBL-esx403.ad.gbl.com 10008C7CFF20D0A8 1:Module:7 1:FC_Port:7:3
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use colons instead of spaces in the `printf` command where needed?

Answer (score 1):

Something more flexible than your code (which will become huge if number of fields increases):

```
awk '
BEGIN{
   nCol = split("4 5 7 8 9", chgSepCol)
   for(i=1; i<=nCol;  i++){
       chgSep[chgSepCol[i]]
   }   
}
{
    for(i=1; i<NF; i++){
        sep = (i in chgSep)? ":" : OFS
        printf "%s%s", $i, sep
    }
    print $NF
}' file
```

String `"4 5 7 8 9"` represents the columns after which the separator must be changed